# Coq/SSReflect: How to do case analysis when reflecting && and /\

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

I have the following reflect predicate:

```
Require Import mathcomp.ssreflect.all_ssreflect.

Inductive reflect (P : Prop) (b : bool) : Prop :=
| ReflectT (p : P) (e : b = true)
| ReflectF (np : ~ P) (e :  b = false).
```

And I am trying to relate the boolean conjunction to the logical one and the following one-line proof goes through:

```
Lemma andP (b1 b2 : bool) : reflect (b1 /\ b2) (b1 && b2).
Proof.
  case b1; case b2; constructor =>//; by case.
Qed.
```

---

However, I don't understand how the last `; by case.` is applied. When we examine the proof without the last `; by case.`:

```
Lemma andP (b1 b2 : bool) : reflect (b1 /\ b2) (b1 && b2).
Proof.
  case b1; case b2; constructor =>//.
```

We get 6 subgoals (2 are trivially true):

```
6 subgoals (ID 45)

  b1, b2 : bool
  ============================
  true /\ false

subgoal 2 (ID 46) is:
 true && false = true
subgoal 3 (ID 116) is:
 false /\ true
subgoal 4 (ID 117) is:
 false && true = true
subgoal 5 (ID 187) is:
 false /\ false
subgoal 6 (ID 188) is:
 false && false = true
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here because they all are `false` - how can we prove that? I tried doing `. case.` individually but that doesn't work. How does `; by case` admit these subgoals all at once?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of sequential composition for tactics changed a bit in recent years. Nowadays, tactics like `constructor` can backtrack while executing their continuation.  Because your definition of `reflect` is a bit different from the standard one, if you just call `constructor`, Coq will immediately apply `ReflectT`, leading to a stuck goal in three of the cases:

```
Lemma andP (b1 b2 : bool) : reflect (b1 /\ b2) (b1 && b2).
Proof.
case b1; case b2=> /=.
- constructor=> //.
- (* constructor. *) (* Stuck *)
```

When you use sequential composition, the `constructor` tactic backtracks, correctly finding the `ReflectF` constructor.

```
  constructor; by try case.
- constructor; by try case.
- constructor; by try case.
Qed.
```

Comment: Oh, thanks I didn't notice the difference when skimmed the definition!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting 6 subgoals: `case b1; case b2; constructor` produces 4 subgoals, corresponding to the four possible cases for combinations of boolean values:

```
  true /\ true

subgoal 2 (ID 13) is:
 ~ (true /\ false)
subgoal 3 (ID 15) is:
 ~ (false /\ true)
subgoal 4 (ID 17) is:
 ~ (false /\ false)
```

The first one is considered trivial by `//`.

`Set Printing Coercions` will tell you that your subgoals or actually as follows:

```
  is_true true /\ is_true true

subgoal 2 (ID 13) is:
 ~ (is_true true /\ is_true false)
subgoal 3 (ID 15) is:
 ~ (is_true false /\ is_true true)
subgoal 4 (ID 17) is:
 ~ (is_true false /\ is_true false)
```

Unfolding `is_true` might help: `case b1; case b2; constructor; rewrite /is_true.`:

```
  true = true /\ true = true

subgoal 2 (ID 19) is:
 ~ (true = true /\ false = true)
subgoal 3 (ID 20) is:
 ~ (false = true /\ true = true)
subgoal 4 (ID 21) is:
 ~ (false = true /\ false = true)
```

The 3 last subgoal are of the form `(_ /\ _) -> False` (because `~ P` stands for `not P`, which unfolds to `P -> False`.

Thus the `case` tactic added after `constructor` destructs the top assumptions turning the last three goals into the following:

```
  true = true -> false = true -> False

subgoal 2 (ID 145) is:
 false = true -> true = true -> False
subgoal 3 (ID 155) is:
 false = true -> false = true -> False
```

Here, we have `false = true` as one of the assumptions in each subgoal, meaning we got a contradiction that SSReflect can immediately recognize and finish the proof using the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).